# How to pass xsl variable as a parameter to javascript function within script tag?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have tried the following code :

```
<xsl:variable name="xx" select="'40967.6424503935'"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   time({$xx});
</script>
```

My intention is to display text via document.write() present in time(). But it didnt give any result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curly braces are for 'Attribute Value Templates', but in this case you are not creating an attribute here, just a normal text node. I think you need to do something like this

```
<xsl:variable name="xx" select="'40967.6424503935'"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   time(<xsl:value-of select="$xx" />);
</script>
```

Comment: iv got it working like this : var curDate = "<xsl:value-of select="$date"/>";
        document.write('<span style="font-size:10px;font-family: arial;font-weight:bold;">['+time(curDate)+"]</span>");

Answer (score 1):

There should be a small correction in the above code snippet. The parameter should be passed within single inverted comma.

```
<xsl:variable name="xx" select="'40967.6424503935'"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   time('<xsl:value-of select="$xx" />');
</script>
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="title" select="{COL[@name='title']}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('title').value);
</script>
```

This works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).